# C# to Xaml Conversion

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to implement a custom accordion ui element but the code has been written in C# ( https://github.com/Kimserey/AccordionView ) but I want to use xaml. I tried to add Accordion view in my content but while I am compiling I get following error

HomePage.xaml : error : The given key was not present in the dictionary.

Here is the my xaml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:customaccordionmenu="clr-namespace:CustomAccordionMenu"
             x:Class="CustomAccordionMenu.HomePage" Title="Accordion Example" >
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions = "Center">            
            <customaccordionmenu:AccordionView/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

So I just want to create an accordionview and add the content in xaml, not in c#

PS: The project is for Xamarin.Forms

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to instantiate an empty AccordionView. Judging by the code in github, the accordionview doesn't have a parameterless constructor, which could cause a problem.

Also the AccordionSectionView class calls

```
private ImageSource _arrowRight = ImageSource.FromFile("ic_keyboard_arrow_right_white_24dp.png");
```

as well as

```
private ImageSource _arrowDown = ImageSource.FromFile("ic_keyboard_arrow_down_white_24dp.png");
```

so if these files aren't in your app's resources and named in the very same way, this is also a possible cause for a crash.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. I've added the images its fine and for the constructor you are right. But how I add the itemtemplate via xaml? Should I bind ? Should I bind an ItemTemplate?

Comment: Actually, i would simply copy the relevant code into my project and make the changes myself since that project isn't that large and should be easy to include file by file. Also I assume the author never intended to instantiate the view empty, however if you include it in xaml it would be instantiated parameterless and anything you bind to it would be added after the constructor has run through.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to convert somehow to xaml.